# AWS for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have setup `AWS` in my `Unity` game and it works fine in the editor and on Android but when I test it on iOS it doesn't seem to access `AWS` properly.

I have added the `NSAppTransportSecurity` elements to my `info.plist` file but that doesn't seem to help.

If it helps, the services I'm using are `Cognito and SimpleDB`.

This is the error I get from the Xcode debugger when trying to access AWS:

> NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object
>   instance was required.   at Amazon.AWSConfigs.get_LoggingConfig ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityConfig..ctor ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Amazon.CognitoIdentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient..ctor
>   (Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint
>   region) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials..ctor (System.String
>   accountId, System.String identityPoolId, System.String unAuthRoleArn,
>   System.String authRoleArn, Amazon.RegionEndpoint region) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at GameControl.get_Credentials

Thanks for any help

EDIT:

This is how my references to Cognito and SimpleDB are set up:

```
    private CognitoAWSCredentials _credentials;

public CognitoAWSCredentials Credentials
{
    get
    {
        if (_credentials == null)
            _credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials("IDENTITY_POOL_HERE", RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
        return _credentials;
    }
}

private AmazonSimpleDBClient _simpleDB;

public AmazonSimpleDBClient SimpleDB
{
    get
    {
        if (_simpleDB == null)
        {
            //Connect to the DB
                _simpleDB = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(
                    credentials: Credentials, 
                    region: RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        }
        return _simpleDB;
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
//Disable SSL certification (This prevents "authentication or decryption has failed" error and "Invalid certificate")
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
       delegate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                               System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                               System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
       {
           return true; // **** Always accept
       };

    username = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Identity");

    if (username == null || username == "")
    {
        username = Credentials.GetIdentityId();
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Identity", username);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    //Check if this user has any bots yet (if they do that we don't need to do the first time setup)
    string selectExpression = "Select count(*) From Bots where UserName = '" + username + "'";
    var selectRequestAction = new SelectRequest { SelectExpression = selectExpression };
    var selectResponse = SimpleDB.Select(selectRequestAction);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet? How are you accessing AWS?

Comment: I added code snippets above. Could it possibly be from disabling the SSL certification? Only problem is it doesn't work without this.. In the editor at least.

Comment: Your mobile app should not be interacting directly with the database in the first place. It's possible for any user to extract your SimpleDB credentials from the application and use them to perform any queries against your database.

Comment: They only have access to run SimpleDB queries. The unauthorised credentials from the identity pool can be restricted to particular domains of SimpleDB. Is there some other service you suggest I use? Either way I need to get past this issue before I can use AWS in iOS.

Comment: So I've tried going back to basics, creating a brand new project with the AWS Unity example packages. All compiles nicely and works in the editor, didn't have to change a single piece of code (just entered my identity pool id and endpoints). I build it as an xcode project and then run it on my iPhone and nothing refuses to work.

Does anyone have any clue what this is? It seems like AWS just doesn't work on iOS.